# javascript/jquery: responding to a user clicking "ok" on an alert dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, alert

my code:

```
alert('Some message');
```

Question 1:

How to execute code that comes after `alert()` when user finished interacting with alert box?

Question 2:

How to detect if user pressed `OK` or `Cancel` on alert box ?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Question 1:

The `alert` method blocks execution until the user closes it:

```
alert('Some message');
alert('doing something else after the first alert is closed by the user');
```

Question 2:

use the [`confirm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.confirm) function:

```
if (confirm('Some message')) {
    alert('Thanks for confirming');
} else {
    alert('Why did you press cancel? You should have confirmed');
}
```

Answer (score 17):

The code after the `alert()` call won't be executed until the user clicks ok to the alert, so just put the code you need *after* the `alert()` call.

If you want a nicer floating dialog than the default javascript `confirm()` popup, see [jQuery UI: floating window](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation)

Answer (score 12):

```
var r = confirm("Press a button!");
if (r == true) {
    alert("You pressed OK!");
}
else {
    alert("You pressed Cancel!");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/epJGG/