# Prevent disabling of alert boxes with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

is there any way to prevent the users choice to disable alert boxes called with

```
    alert("Hello");
```

or

```
    confirm("Click 'OK' or 'Cancel'");
```

?

The problem is that I need these alert boxes for some purposes. So if the user marks the checkbox in this alert box to disable them, they won't show up anymore and the further steps will fail.

I'm checking the choice confirmed on this alert box with

```
    if (confirm('Some message')) {
        alert('Thanks for confirming');
    } else {
        alert('Why did you press cancel? You should have confirmed');
    }
```

(Code found here: [Click me!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275512/javascript-jquery-responding-to-a-user-clicking-ok-on-an-alert-dialog?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: I don't know what _"prevent the users choice to disable alert boxes"_ means.

Comment: If you get an alert box called with jQuery, you have the opportunity to disable further alert boxes in the website. And if you confirm that by clicking on the checkbox which is ALWAYS there (standard), then no alert boxes will appear anymore. And this is what I want to prevent from happening.

Comment: that's part of the browser and has nothing to do with javascript. Use a different UI approach with html elements if it's critical

Comment: If you make popups your users don't want to see, then your design is wrong.

Comment: Actually, the boxes are only visible in the admin center panel. 
I think you misunderstood a little thing, I WANT the user to see them, thats why I tried to prevent the disable method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is handled by the browser, so you can´t directly disable it. As far as I know, this is a chrome only feature.

You got two choices:

- Don´t create multiple alert boxes (The option to disable alert boxes are displayed when they are occurring "too often".)
- Use a custom alert box like jquery UI. ([jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#default))

Comment: You don't know far enough, also Firefox implements this feature.

Comment: Well.. How many browser has implemented this is pointless to discuss.. You can´t override the browser.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. The jQuery UI Dialog looks nice though. I'll take a look on this.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. Would recommend that you make your own dialog messages using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and [jQuery UI dialog widget](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/).

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look on this then.